# What is a good way to store NLP-Embeddings (nparrays plus information)

Tags: python, database, numpy

I have huge text datasets (500.000+ Documents) and I want to store embeddings for all sentences or paragraphs in a document. An embeddings is a numpy array with 768 entries.

I know that one can easily write numpy arrays to disk, but I also need to store additional information for these embeddings, namely which sentence/paragraph do they represent and the document in which the sentence occurs. 
I thought about storing all these information in a (PostgreSQL) database, however I fear that searching for vectors/embeddings might be slow. The application is similarity search, so finding the most similar vectors to a query.
What is the best way of storing these vectors and their corresponding info? Is it efficient to store python tuples, in this case (document_ID, sentence_as_string, sentence_embedding)? Does a postgres database do the job?
I have also thought about storing all embeddings as a numpy matrix in a .npy file and store just
the row number for the embedding in the database. This would mean loading all embeddings into memory, but I feel like this might be the best for performance. Is it 'messy'? Are there best practices about storing numpy arrays plus additional information?

Edit (Additional Info):
I have several datasets, like the [Enron Corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enron_Corpus), which I want to split into sentences or paragraphs. Let's call them units. For each unit, I want to calculate a [sentence embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_embedding). These Vectors have 768 dimension. As I want to search for the most similar vectors, I need to calculate the cosine-similarity between all vectors. I would also like to calculate the cosine-similarity between all vectors and the embedding of a search query, which makes the comparison between all vectors necessary.
Now my question is how to store these information effectively. The application seems to fit a classic relational database scheme. A document consists of several units, each unit has a text field. I suppose that one could also store a 768-dimensional vector as an entry in the database, so a unit can also have its embedding stored. However, I fear that calculating the cosine-similarity might be pretty slow inside the database, compared to having all embeddings in memory. But when I store all embeddings as a numpy array and load them into the memory, I lose the info on what unit produced which emebedding. So my question is, how to best store this large amount of 768-dimensional vectors and their corresponding information.
Calculating embeddings is expensive. I want to do it only once. So the workflow is:

1. split all the documents into units (Text, Meta-Information as Text)
2. calculate the embeddings for all units (Numpy-Arrays)
3. **store them**
4. be able to search them

Storing them is what gives me headaches.

Further endeavors:
I have already set up the database without the embeddings. Afterwards I investigated how one would store a numpy array inside a postgres-DB. Apparently, one has to serialize it to JSON. This makes calculating the cosine-similarity inside the Database pretty much impossible(or at least impossibly slow) AFAIK. I do not believe that it's worth the time to put all my embeddings into a postgresDB right now. There also seem to be some google courses about working with embeddings, which I will check out.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail, particularly about the data’s format and how it is used?

Comment: Just saw your edit! I’ll give it some thought, this seems like a potentially interesting problem.

Comment: @Angus did you get a good answer to this eventually? I'm in the same position and wondering what's the best form of storage for sentence embeddings.

Comment: @lppier Whether it actually is a good answer remains to be seen. I have implemented a faiss index for storing the actual embeddings. It produces manageable overhead, is easy to implement and makes storing the embeddings really easy. The performance is poor so far, but the hardware for testing is not capable as of now. I'm storing the text information inside a postgres-db and reference the embeddings via id.

Comment: @Angus what do you mean by performance is poor? Search wise or time performance wise?

Comment: @lppier time performance wise.

Comment: @Angus did you get a good answer to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

[For Python] Storing all of the embeddings in memory at runtime would not be great idea. Instead, after you calculate the embeddings, save them into a file and whenever you want to search for the 'most similar phrase', run through the file one line at a time, calculate the cosine similarity score, and keep track of the max score and the sentence corresponding to that embedding (you could structure the file as a json). Doing it in this manner should allow the program to be able to search through all the embeddings without loading every single embedding into memory.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea for how to search similar sentences without storing all the embeddings .

My basic idea is to look for similar sentences where we need to do.
in my case , my sentences are clustred in differente clusters and for each cluster I assosiated a key.
Now to find similar sentences for a given sentence , i need to identifie the key that correspond for my sentence , then I can search for similar sentences just in a small cluster( using the key) , we store only the embeddings for each sentences of the cluster.

to storing word embedding i have tried [annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy)
(to searching similarity between words embeddings) associated to [lmdb databse](https://lmdb.readthedocs.io/en/release/)
where i stocked the id for each word embeddings  added to annoy indexer and the corresponding word .

Answer (score -2):

I think [Redis](https://redis.io) is perfect for your case. Just store the text field as a key and the embedding as a value. There is a good [python implementation](https://pypi.org/project/redis/).